# Can't position img inside an inner content div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I can't seem to position the image around the text. I am working with wordpress. I tried many solutions with the float property with no effect. The content is placed in an inner content div, maybe that will help. The html is like the following:

```
img class="alignright size-medium" src="http://www.puregraze.com/images/paginas/114_kaas_klein.jpg" alt="Puregraze Graskaas" width="640" height="480"
```

around this text:

```
<h2>De Graskaas van Pure Graze®: lang verwacht, toch gekomen!</h2>
<h2>Gra(a)skaas</h2>


Een heerlijke kaas, romig, gemaakt van volle melk!

Ze smaakt pittig, is jong voor haar leeftijd en smelt op je tong!
De nasmaak is prettig en fris.

Dat is Pure Graze® Gra(a)sKaas!

Deze kaas is gemaakt met behulp van alleen natuurlijke middelen en is, door het gebruik van microbieel stremsel, ook geschikt voor vegetariërs.

Ga naar 1 van de <a title="verkooppunten graskaas" href="http://puregraze.com/consument-retail-horeca/waar-te-koop/is-pure-graze-vlees-verkrijgbaar/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">verkooppunten</a> of bestel de Pure Graze® Gra(a)sKaas in onze <a title="Graskaas webwinkel" href="http://puregraze.com/webwinkel/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">webwinkel</a>.

Geniet er van!
```

This how it is supposed to look like:

https://www.google.nl/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBypOVwb3VAhXDYlAKHXSXAJ4QjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.spoongraphics.co.uk%2Ftutorials%2Fwrapping-text-around-an-image-in-illustrator&psig=AFQjCNFeNvCD88DZijVS12b68drJuctu1w&ust=1501933696149010

Comment: what you need exactly ? provide a fiddle or snippet

Comment: add a working snippet.

Comment: Using float, you can position text around an image, but not really the other way around. I think we could use a mocked up screen shot of what the result is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need? You have to view full page because of the size of the image.

EDIT: I changed the size of the image

```css
img { float: left; margin-right: 1em; }
```

```html
<img class="alignright size-medium" src="http://www.puregraze.com/images/paginas/114_kaas_klein.jpg" alt="Puregraze Graskaas" width="320" height="240">
<h2>De Graskaas van Pure Graze®: lang verwacht, toch gekomen!</h2>
<h2>Gra(a)skaas</h2>
Een heerlijke kaas, romig, gemaakt van volle melk! Ze smaakt pittig, is jong voor haar leeftijd en smelt op je tong! De nasmaak is prettig en fris. Dat is Pure Graze® Gra(a)sKaas! Deze kaas is gemaakt met behulp van alleen natuurlijke middelen en is,
door het gebruik van microbieel stremsel, ook geschikt voor vegetariërs. Ga naar 1 van de <a title="verkooppunten graskaas" href="http://puregraze.com/consument-retail-horeca/waar-te-koop/is-pure-graze-vlees-verkrijgbaar/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">verkooppunten</a>of bestel de Pure Graze® Gra(a)sKaas in onze <a title="Graskaas webwinkel" href="http://puregraze.com/webwinkel/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">webwinkel</a>. Geniet er van!
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it stays right in the middle where it is. A link to the site might make it easier: http://puregraze.directdev.nl/consument-retail-horeca/graasproducten/graaskaas/

Comment: Your edited version worked for me! I don't know if you solved with with the margin-right or the changed image size. Thanks!!

Comment: The margin is just to put a little space between the image and the text.